# How do I select the value with the lowest "count" in a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, lodash

Through the use of lodash's _.countBy function, I have generated a tally object, counting the number of times a value occurs in an array.

What would be the best method to select the lowest count in the "value -> count" object?

```
 var/input = ["A","A","B","B","C"];
 var/tally = _.countBy(input); // Tally is {"A":2, "B":2, "C":1}

 // [...solution...]

 Console.assert(lowest == "C");
```

No special handling of ties is required, provided it's tied for the lowest count. Lodash is available.

Comment: It can be rephrased, give me a sec

Comment: I do think the question needs some work but I retracted my close vote after giving it a closer read

Comment: The question says `lodash`, but the tag says `underscore.js`. Which are you actually using? I know they're similar, but not identical, so you should tag correctly.

Comment: I thought they were the same, and `underscore.js` was an old name for `lodash`. I have corrected the tags.

Comment: I want the item that occurs the least in the input array. I used `_.countBy` to assist this, but there may be ways of doing it without using `_.countBy`. They might be better, I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could reduce the array of keys and get the smallest key by checking the value.

```js
var tally = { A: 2, B: 2, C: 1 },
    lowest = Object.keys(tally).reduce((a, b) => tally[a] < tally[b] ? a : b);

console.log(lowest);
```

A lodash approach by pairing the properties and getting the minimum with at index 1 and taking the first element of the array.

```js
var input = ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C"],
    lowest = _(input)
        .countBy()                    // { A: 2, B: 2, C: 1 }
        .toPairs()                    // [["A", 2], ["B", 2], ["C", 1]]
        .minBy(1)                     // ["C", 1]
        [0];

console.log(lowest);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by the following:

```js
var tally = {"A":2, "B":2, "C":1};

var tallyItemSmallestKey = Object
.entries(tally)
.sort((entry0, entry1) => entry0[1] - entry1[1] < 0 ? -1 : 1)
.map(entry => entry[0])[0];

console.log( tallyItemSmallestKey );
```

Answer (score 0):

That could be shortened to a non `_` solution if you sort the input array:

```
const input = ["A","A","B","B","C"].sort();

let curr = { count: 0 }, result = { count: 0 };
for(const value of input) {
  if(value === curr.value) curr.count++;
  else curr = { value, count: 1 };

  if(curr.count > result.count) result = curr;
}

console.log(result.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the tallies, then check for the min

```js
const input = ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C"]

// get counts
const tally = input.reduce((obj, char) => {
  if(!obj[char])
   obj[char]=1
  else
   obj[char]++
  return obj
}, {})

// get min
let char = Reflect.ownKeys(tally).reduce((keep,current)=>{
  if(!keep) keep = current
  if(tally[current] < tally[keep])
     keep = current
  return keep
}, '')

console.log(char)
console.log(`'${char}' == 'A'`,char == 'A')
console.log(`'${char}' == 'C'`,char == 'C')
```

Answer (score 0):

With lodash you could use [`countBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#countBy), [`entries`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#toPairs) and [`minBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#minBy) for something like this:

```js
const input = ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C"]

const result = _.minBy(_.entries(_.countBy(input)), 1)
console.log(_.head(result))  // or just result[0]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Or via lodash chaining:

```js
const input = ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C"]

const result = _(input).countBy().entries().minBy(1)

console.log(_.head(result)) // or just result[0]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You could also do this with ES6 with `Array.reduce`, `Array.sort` & `Object.entries`:

```js
const input = ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C"]

const countBy = arr => arr.reduce((r,c) => (r[c] = (r[c] || 0) + 1, r), {})
const min = arr => arr.sort((a,b) => a[1] - b[1])[0] // sort asc and take first
console.log(min(Object.entries(countBy(input)))[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to import everything that lodash has to offer, you can't use chaining. This is a [`_.flow()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flow) based version of [Nina's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53289943/5157454):

```js
const { flow, countBy, entries, partialRight, minBy, last, head } = _;

const input = ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C"];

const getByLowestCount = flow([
  countBy,
  entries,
  partialRight(minBy, last),
  head
]);

const result = getByLowestCount(input);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```